# how to get parent child of row in jquery datatable for each function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

i have implemented  jquery datatable. on button click i have to get all selected row data from table and for this i have added "SelectedRow" class to each row. my  code is

```
 $("#frmSubmitCSVProduct").live('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Barcodes = "";

        oTable = $('#tblCsvUPCList').dataTable();


        $.each(oTable.fnGetData(), function (i, row) {
            alert(row);
            });
});
```

in alert i got
"44848448,item no. 4,item3,item4,30,famous item,Beer,"

bui i want just data of selected row, which has selected class
may selected row is

```
<tr id="tr35841256" data-barcode="35841256" style="cursor: pointer;" class="SelectedRow">
<td class=" sorting_1">35841256</td>
<td class="">item no. 4</td>
<td class="">item3,item4</td>
<td class=""><input type="button" value="Select" id="btnSelectProduct" class="btn"></td></tr>
```

i just want this selected row from my table, another fields are hidden, how can i do this

Comment: this link might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109821/how-to-get-the-selected-table-cell-value-in-datatable)

Comment: also those values had been alerted because its inside your for each. move your alert outside the for loop. `alert($(this).find(".yourCellIdHere").html());`